How to download pymysql
my mac cannot update anymore, it is 2017air , and now it stop at macOS Monterey 12.7.4. Everytime I  pip install the dominal shows could not find a version. I already download mysql 8.0.28 by dmg document, but cannot find a good way to download a adaption pymysql.
I cannot install wheel tool by pip install too. Now I have PyMySQL-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl. who can help me???

Using built-in python, or one installed via macports/brew? Perhaps you can provide you pip --version

Thank you friend, I will try it!
by the way, sudo pip install works better than pip install. It can work sometimes.
